# how to get email, display name, number using the phone number chooser task for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am trying to get email, Display name and mobile number form phone number chooser task but it only give s display name and phone number in return i also want email to be returned as-well. it can be done by email address chooser task for Windows Phone 8  but than it will not give phone number so how to achieve  it .to get all 3 details in one event

[email address chooser code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394016(v=vs.105).aspx)

[phone number chooser task code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394021(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have to search the contact list given the data output of one of those pickers and get the matching entry if you want all the information.

So lets do an example with `PhoneNumberChooserTask`

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

// create the phone number chooser
PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();

// user has chose a contact from the list
void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        // At this point, we know the Phone Number and Display Name only
        // so lets search for all Contacts that have the same Phone Number and Display Name

        // create the search, we are going to filter by Display Name and past the Phone Number as the third variable (state)            
        Contacts cons = new Contacts();
        cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);
        cons.SearchAsync(e.DisplayName, FilterKind.DisplayName, e.PhoneNumber);
    }
}

// search is complete
// lets use some LINQ and select out the matching data we want (magic.. I know)
void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    Contact fullcontact = null;

    // query
    var q = from contact in e.Results
            from pn in contact.PhoneNumbers
            where pn.PhoneNumber.Equals((string)e.State, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            select contact;

    // loop through all the matches (should be 1, if any)
    foreach (Contact c in q)
    {
       // save the contact
       fullcontact = c;   
    }                 


    // at this point fullcontact should contain everything if not null
    // loop through the phone numbers/emails (usually they will only contain 1
    // (unless, you really like to keep your contacts upto date)
    if(fullcontact != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(fullcontact.DisplayName);

        // loop phone numbers
        foreach(ContactPhoneNumber cpn in fullcontact.PhoneNumbers)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cpn.PhoneNumber);
        }

        // loop emails
        foreach(ContactEmailAddress cea in fullcontact.EmailAddresses)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cea.EmailAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check my code which i have added to your code but it does not return correct value for phone number and email so what iam doing wrong in that code please look into it @Chubosaurus Software

Comment: @SmartDeveloper look at the structure for the Contact class.  A single Contact can contain many PhoneNumbers and many Email Addresses.  You can't ToString them, you have to treat them as a list.

Comment: @SmartDeveloper hmm, you should know how to loop through a collection by now; but sure why not.  I updated the solution.